# IIS not logging in azure cloud service

Tags: iis, azure, windows-server-2012

I am not sure if this is to do with my application or IIS so I have asked on SO. I want to be able to see all http requests that arrive at my web server. When I look at the IIS logging for my site, I can see the location of the logs:

[image: iisdirectory]

---

It seems that the logging is enabled - this is the right-hand-pane:

[image]

---

However, when I look at the folder, the last log files are from about a month ago:

[image]

---

So far I have tried: -

1. Restart the server.
2. Checked the permission of the folder and made sure that IIS_IUSRS have write permission (which they do).
3. Enabling logging with appcmd:

   ```
   appcmd set config /section:httpLogging /dontLog:False
   appcmd set config /section:httpLogging /dontLog:False /selectiveLogging:LogAll
   appcmd set config "<mysite>" -section:system.webServer/httpLogging /dontLog:"false" /commit:apphost
   appcmd set config "<mysite>" -section:system.webServer/httpLogging /selectiveLogging:"LogAll"
   ```
4. Emptied the folder in case I am using up some quota.
5. I have followed instructions [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754631%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), [here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httplogging) and [here](http://upport.microsoft.com/kb/930909).

Nothing has helped so far. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would try is to RDP to the VM and use task manager to terminate WaIISHost.exe or WaHostBootstrapper.exe. This will cause IISConfigurator to re-run and rebuild the application pool for your site. Then test to see if IIS generates the log files.  You can read a little more about terminating the process (and the automatic recycle) at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/09/05/how-to-modify-a-running-azure-service.aspx, and the role startup process (including IISConfigurator) at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2011/05/05/windows-azure-role-architecture.aspx.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it did not seem to help. I will try some variations around this.